# Alphabetize Options from Object Preserving Key/Value Associations in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-options

What I need, is to be able to sort a select element's child option nodes by their text, while maintaining their value associations. I can either get them to alphabetize and disassociate from their keys, or I can associate their keys without alphabetization.

I know there is a method for accessing JSON directly, but this is a phased implementation, and that functionality will come later. For now, I must load the json via precursory script block to when the app script `MyInterface.js` is loaded.

I've researched custom filters, but that's where the disassociation from the keys comes from. If the JSON needs to be in an entirely different format, I'd be willing to adopt it.

Here's what I've got...

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="MyInterface" ng-controller="SimpleJSON">
      <select name="index_category"
        ng-model="IndexCategory"
        ng-init="IndexCategory = IndexCategory || '0'"
        ng-options="option in JSON.Categories | orderObjectBy:'val'">
        <option value="0">Select Animal...</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <script>
      var json = {
        "123":"Zebra",
        "456":"Monkey",
        "789":"Anteater"
      };
    </script>
    <script src="MyInterface.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**MyInterface.js**

```
(function(json) {

  // AngularJS Module
  var MyInterface = angular.module('MyInterface', []);

  // Custom Filters
  MyInterface.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
    return function(items, field, reverse) {
      var filtered = [];
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        filtered.push(item);
      });
      filtered.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1;
      });
      if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
      return filtered;
    };
  });

  // Controllers
  MyInterface.controller('SimpleJSON', function($scope) {
    $scope.JSON = angular.fromJson(json);
  });

})(json);
```

Essentially what the selection needs to have option-wise is:

```
<option value="0">Select Animal...</option>
<option value="789">Anteater</option>
<option value="456">Monkey</option>
<option value="123">Zebra</option>
```

## Alterations Incorporating Accepted Answer

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="MyInterface" ng-controller="SimpleJSON">
      <select name="index_category"
        ng-model="IndexCategory"
        ng-options="option.value for option in JSON track by option.key">
        <option value="">Select Animal...</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <script>
      var json = [
        { key:"123", value:"Zebra" },
        { key:"456", value:"Monkey" },
        { key:"789", value:"Anteater" }
      ];
    </script>
    <script src="MyInterface.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**MyInterface.js**

```
(function(json) {

  // AngularJS Module
  var MyInterface = angular.module('MyInterface', []);

  // Controllers
  MyInterface.controller('SimpleJSON', function($scope, orderByFilter) {

    // Load JSON
    $scope.JSON = angular.fromJson(json);

    // Alphabetize by Value
    $scope.JSON = orderByFilter($scope.JSON, 'value');

  });

})(json);
```

Comment: Can't you transform the object to an array of objects?

Comment: What would that do for me? Still kinda new to Angular.

Comment: Just want to add that it's a fairly bad idea to use `JSON` as a variable, both local and global, seeing as the built-in JSON library resides there (`JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`). It would be like overwriting the `document` global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use array of objects with ng-options.
i.e , Example

```
 $scope.animals= [
    {key:"123", value:"Zebra"},
    {key:"456",value: "Monkey"},
    {key:"789", value: "Anteater"}
  ];
```

and since you only want key in the `ng-model` you would need to use syntax `ng-options="option.key as option.value for option in animals | orderBy:'value'"`. And for default option just provide an option with `value=""`

```
<select name="index_category" ng-model="IndexCategory" ng-options="option.key as option.value for option in animals| orderBy:'value'">
    <option value="">Select Animal...</option>
</select>
```

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.JSON = [{
    key: "123",
    value: "Zebra"
  }, {
    key: "456",
    value: "Monkey"
  }, {
    key: "789",
    value: "Anteater"
  }];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select name="index_category" ng-model="IndexCategory" ng-options="option.key as option.value for option in JSON | orderBy:'value'">
    <option value="">Select Animal...</option>
  </select>
  {{IndexCategory}}
</div>
```

Also you need to remember DOM filters are expensive as they run twice atleast during the digest cycle. If your select list is dynamic do not place DOM filter, instead you could just sort it in your controller before binding the data. In your case you could just either use a simple native sort or the orderBy filter itself in the controller.

i.e

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, orderByFilter) {
  $scope.animals= [{
    key: "123",
    value: "Zebra"
  }, {
    key: "456",
    value: "Monkey"
  }, {
    key: "789",
    value: "Anteater"
  }];
  /*Using orderByFilter*/
  $scope.animals= orderByFilter($scope.JSON, 'value');
  /*Or just use native sort*/
  //$scope.animals.sort(function(a, b){ return a['value'] > b['value'] });

});
```

and your view would just be:

```
 ng-options="option.key as option.value for option in animals">
```

If you do not have an option to get the data in array format from the server and you need to transform, just do it in your controller like:

```
$scope.animals = convertToOptions(optionsObject);

function convertToOptions(obj){
    var options = [];
    angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key){
        options.push({key:key, value:value});
    });
    return options;
  }
```

If you are really concerned about setting the option value same as that of the `key` property you would need to use `track by`. i.e

```
  ng-options="option.value for option in animals track by option.key">
```

*Side Note: Do not use ng-init with ng-options.*

From documentation:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

Comment: Would it be possible to get rid of the filter entirely?

Comment: Yes see my last section.

Comment: Looking at the code snippet, you've lost the key associations like I did. Their values are all 0, 1, 2

Comment: WHen working with angular do not see DOM, you would just deal with ng-model. It is angular responsibility to create and manage select options and how it does the mapping. If at all they need to have the value then you need to use `track by`

Comment: Odd, I tried using `track by` in one of my attempts and it never produced what I was looking for.

Comment: @Pentagear See the last update. You cannot use `select as` with `track by` as they are not meants to work together, meaning the ngmodel would be the respective selected object.

Comment: Aha! With your help I got it working. Key associations are preserved and list is alphabetized. Thank you as well for the additional best-practices tips on initialization.

Answer (score 0):

ngOptions in Angular 1.x does not currently support ordering object properties.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1286

**However**, you can apply the custom `toArray` filter linked below to convert the object to an array, then chain the `orderBy` filter after the `toArray` conversion filter:

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-toArrayFilter

```
item in items | toArray | orderBy: 'date'
```